# JRadioButtonGroup: nullPointerException with getSelection().getActionCommand()

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

Properly following all instructions from my course slides and StackOverflow-answers, I keep on getting the same nullPointerException. It's about a ButtonGroup of JRadioButtons of which I am trying to get the selected value to use it further in my code. As you can see, I set the actionCommand and did -as I see it- everything correctly.
Here it is:

```
String[] diffLevels = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
    JRadioButton[] diffLevelButtons = new JRadioButton[diffLevels.length];
    JPanel diffLevButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    diffLevButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
    ButtonGroup diffLevelGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    for (int i = 0; i < diffLevels.length; i++) {
        diffLevelButtons[i] = new JRadioButton(diffLevels[i]);
        diffLevelButtons[i].setActionCommand(diffLevels[i]);
        diffLevelGroup.add(diffLevelButtons[i]);
        diffLevButtonPanel.add(diffLevelButtons[i]);
    }
String difficultyLevel = diffLevelGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand();
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start game");
        Game myGame = new Game();
        startButton.addActionListener(new StartButtonListener(myGame) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myGame.prepareGame(nbRows,nbColumns,diffLevel,playerMode,player1ChosenName,player2ChosenName);
                GameFrameMaker gameFrameMaker = new GameFrameMaker();
                gameFrameMaker.makeGameFrame(myGame.board);
            }
        });
```

String difficultyLevel  = diffLevelGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand(); works when I put it inside an ActionListener for these buttons (that's what I've tried and it works, just left it out of this piece of code), but then I can't access it from the startButton-ActionListener. (All the other parameters, classes and objects are things that work, so don't worry about them)
Anyone an idea how I could make this work?

Comment: `JRadioButton` is initially unselected. Is one of those buttons selected when the code `diffLevelGroup.getSelection()` is executed? Debug your code and see what value that code returns when none of the `JRadioButton`s is selected.

Comment: or just trust the documentation: "Initially, all buttons in the group are unselected." and "Returns the model of the **selected** button."

Comment: @Abra, I tried debugging it, but when I got to that step, the nullPointerException popped up again and I hadn't got the chance to see the value. None of the buttons has been selected at that moment, because this code generates the frame with these buttons... So user85421, how to retrieve the value of the group then if the frame hasn't been made yet?

Comment: No, none of the buttons are selected because neither the user nor the code selected one. What value do you want to retrieve? There is no `ActionCommand` associated with the group itself (and there is no button selected)

Comment: @user85421, I'd like to get the difficulty level the user selects, because I need it for building the play board of the game I'm trying to make. Is there then a way to access this value áfter the interface has been made?

Comment: but you wrote "the frame hasn't been made yet", how can the user select something? Anyway basically you can add `ActionListener`s to the buttons that react on use input, or add that code inside the listener of the start button, if that is the correct *time* you want to know what is selected (not when the group is being constructed, but when the users press start)

Comment: @user85421, yes, that did the trick! I added it to my startButtonListener :) Thank you! Now I can spend some more time on trying to fix the new bugs